# Laravel "Unauthenticated" error in specific route

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

In my Laravel 7 backend I have some api url like:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function(){
    Route::post('logout/all', 'Auth\LoginController@logoutAll');
    Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
    Route::put('profile/{profile}', 'ProfileController@update');
});
```

The route /logout and /profile/1 work fine, while the route /logout/all gives an error:

```
{
"error": "Unauthenticated"
}
```

The token I use is correct because I can use it for others route and it works.
Of course I didn't call the /logout before trying the /logout/all.

I tried to change the controller function of logoutAll, setting it to "logout":

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function(){
    Route::post('logout/all', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
    Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
    Route::put('profile/{profile}', 'ProfileController@update');
});
```

In this way it works, but this invoke the same function.
That's the code of the function:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Auth::user()->tokens()->where('id', Auth::user()->currentAccessToken()->id)->delete();
    return response()->json(['data' => 'User logged out.'], 200);
}

public function logoutAll(Request $request)
{
    //do nothing
    return response()->json(['data' => 'User loggedAll out.'], 200);
}
```

Help me please.

**UPDATE**

If I use CURL command this is the output:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. in file /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php on line 117

#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php(103): Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(Array, 'POST')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php(40): Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Array)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php(162): Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection->handleMatchedRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), NULL)
...
```

Comment: Often when the problem doesn’t make sense the issue is cache. You have tended to clear your cache with "php artisan config: cache" and "php artisan cache:clear"?

Comment: I tried "php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache" but without changes

Comment: This may sound strange, but rename the LoginController controller to something else, and try using something like LoginController2@logoutAll. I've seen the case that the cache persisted ...

Comment: I have update my question with more details if its can help you

Comment: I tried to rename (duplicate) LoginController, same error.

Comment: Do you have a production and development environment in the postman? Is it correct?

Comment: No ok, I found the problem. In the __constructor() method i have: $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout'); If i comment it works.

Comment: Seems like, the `logout` and `profile/{id}` pre defined and you just make `logoutAll`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the __constructor() method

```
$this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
```

I change it to:

```
$this->middleware('guest')->except(['logout', 'logoutAll']);
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked pre defined or not. Cheers!!!

Comment: glad you figured it out ... can you mark your own answer as the accepted answer so this question is considered closed and answered?